# Error occurred when add new field on Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Search as a database. By changing requirements, I added a new field on ES. After added it, my NodeJS application threw an error on the line which I added sortable.

My expectation is: update the index mappings for all old documents when I add a new field on ES.

Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: It would be very helpful to see how exactly did you change the mapping, and what error did NodeJS (and Elasticsearch) has returned. In general, the updated mapping will only be used for indexing of the newly added documents, for the old documents to be indexed according to the new mapping you need to [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) them all.

Comment: have you read my expectation yet ?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you want to achieve, that's why I am asking for clarifications.